# Convince Google to display rating schema

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, schema.org

We use aggreagateSchema on our websites in multiple countries (different domain, but the same markup in each country). They're valid and displaying on Google SERPs in some countries.

However, in other countries vast majority of schema rankings are missing from SERP.

One thing I tried was to clear caches in Google Search Console of 2 particular such pages - hoping that Google will re-read them and include the stars on SERPs.

Can you suggest any other means to convince Google to reconsider displaying stars next to such pages on SERPs?

Comment: Your looking for a feature that doesn't exist, Google decides what to display, not you or anyone else for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the schema.org [AggregateRating](https://schema.org/AggregateRating) object? If so that's what I've had success using.

Google doesn't always use the same technologies on all of their sites. They may rank, index, and display sites differently for different products and countries.

I would **guess** that the countries where schema.org isn't working may be using an older version of their technologies. In which case you may try using older types of markup.  Try using combinations of RDFa, microdata and microformats to see which ones each version of Google likes.

Alternatively when your ratings aren't showing up find a site on that same Google product that is and view source to see what type of markup they used.

Also keep in mind that even google views Schema.org as simply a suggestion. They don't use the whole spec for rich-snippets and they tend to change how they parse it from time to time.

Comment: Also check your coding using the rich text tool https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/